# Smooth Scrolling links conflicting w/ fancybox, change href to class or id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this for my scroll transition between a top and bottom div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();//stop the browser from jumping to the anchor
    var href  = $(this).attr('href'),
        oset  = $(href).offset().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop : oset
    }, 1000, function () {
        location.hash = href;
    });
});

</script>
```

But it's conflicting with how I'm using fancybox as it's using 'href', I've tried defining the 'div ids' in place and creating a shared class (eg .smooth and called in both links) but it just broke. How can I use this specifing only two divs for it to apply to?

Question spawning from - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547378/fancybox-with-iframe-js-conflictions-with-my-site-wont-implement

Comment: What is the HTML for it? Why would fancybox be fired upon clicking this link?

Comment: Here's where I've been developing, 'http://tinyurl.com/7dqupdm' click 'gallery' and it's just dead. When I remove the above code, the fancybox for that link works perfect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('#menu a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();//stop the browser from jumping to the anchor
    var href  = $(this).attr('href'),
        oset  = $(href).offset().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop : oset
    }, 1000, function () {
        location.hash = href;
    });
});
```

There is no point in scrolling when 'Gallery' is clicked and opens fancybox.

Comment: Thanks Richard - that worked well for the menu. But I need to incorporate #bottom and #top divs (from left side of page). How could I call multiple divs; (#menu, #bottom, #top a)?

Comment: Yep, Perfect :-) Simply selecting "a" is a little 'greedy'. You could otherwise consider adding a class when you don't want that function to fire: $('a').not('.noScroll').on('click', function (event) {

Comment: Ehm, in your code you made a little mistake, should be: ("#menu a, #bottom a, #top a"). You missed the a's